# Perfect information game

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

Assume that there are two parents A and B who are tempted to pick up their children late. We denote the set of parents $N = {A, B}$. Each parent $i \in N$ chooses from the action set $A^i = {E, L}$ between being early or being late. The game is perfect information. If we denote the opportunity cost of being early $c_e^i$, we have $c_e^A=31$ and $c_e^B=33$. Suppose that for each child that is recollected late there is an implicit cost of $c_{L,e}^B=20$ on each parent. We can denote the total externality that each parent faces as $C_{L,e}(n) = nc_{L,e}$

Would the payoff matrix be something like this:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}(-11,-13)&(11,-13)\\(13,-11)&(13,11)\end{matrix} \right]$$
B in row and A in column.

Comment: Is the $B$ in $c^B_{L,e}$ a typo? What does the $e$ in $c_{L,e}$ and $C_{L,e}$ stand for? What is $n$? Why do parents "face an externality" and what does this mean?

Comment: @VARulle is not a typo, as far as I'm understanding it stands for the parent B. $e$ is an externality, whereas $n$ is the number of parents being late. The externality faced is: The late recollections have some adverse consequences: The kindergarten workers feel that parents are irresponsible and it discourages them from exerting extra effort when taking care of the children.

Comment: If $c^B_{L,e}$ is not a typo, then is there also a $c^A_{L,e}$? Or why do you refer to parent $B$ in the "implicit cost on each parent"?